# python delete the keys that have the value a specific value throughout the json

Tags: python, json, key-value

I have a json that looks like this:

```
  gap_json  = {
    "AbsencePresence": [
      {
         "sample_id": "read1", 
         "seg_1": "D", 
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "23s_SA": "ND", 
         "see": "ND", 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read2", 
         "seg_1": "D", 
         "lukM-F": "ND", 
         "23s_SA": "ND", 
         "see": "D", 
         "sed": "ND"
      }, 
      {
         "sample_id": "read3", 
         "seg_1": "D", 
         "lukM-F": "D", 
         "23s_SA": "ND", 
         "see": "ND", 
         "sed": "ND"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove the keys that have the value 'ND' throughout the json.  For example, example: If "ND" is the value of the key "see" in **each and every** sample_id (read1 AND read2 and read3) then remove the key altogether.  If there is one "ND" in "see", say in read1, and the other two sample_id are "D" then keep "see" and its values.  So I like to end up with the following:

```
gap_json  = {
    "AbsencePresence": [
       {
          "sample_id": "read1", 
          "seg_1": "D", 
          "lukM-F": "D", 
          "see": "ND", 
       }, 
       {
          "sample_id": "read2", 
          "seg_1": "D", 
          "lukM-F": "ND", 
          "see": "D", 
       }, 
       {
          "sample_id": "read3", 
          "seg_1": "D", 
          "lukM-F": "D", 
          "see": "ND", 
       }
    ]
 }
```

I have tried to convert json into a tuple and remove items as I loop through it but with no luck.

Comment: post your attempts..

Answer (score 0):

```
def keep_keys(dicts):
  from itertools import chain
  keys = set(chain.from_iterable(d.keys() for d in dicts))
  for k in keys:
    if not all(d[k] == "ND" for d in dicts):
      yield k
```

this yields all the keys you'd want to keep (takes a list of dictionaries). You can filter yourself, I'd guess.